# Blender Cycles: uniform position-based colors?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I am trying to create an effect where I have several objects (say, cubes) which draw their color from an underlying texture.

Imagine, for example, if I had a rectangular region consisting of side-by-side cubes (or alternatively one large object with many joined cubes). I also have a texture of, say, a rainbow in front of a blue sky.

The effect I desire is that each object draws its color from the texture (i.e., a cube in the top-right corner gets the color of the top-right corner of the texture). Ideally, I would like that each object/cube is colored uniformly, say by extracting the color of the pixel closest to its position. The result would be a very grainy representation of the texture (depending on the resolution of my cubes).

Do you know if such an effect is possible in Blender Cycles?

Comment: Are those cubes static?

Comment: Is this the kind of thing you are looking for ? https://youtu.be/05HFa3jNBH0?t=24

Comment: Yes, we can assume they are static

Comment: @Gorgious: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for - thank you!

Comment: @J.Galt Do tell me if you have trouble achieving it, I'll try to write an answer, he goes pretty fast in the video

Comment: Thank you - I managed to reproduce it! If you want and would like to provide this link as a reponse to this question, I could accept it as the designated answer (so other people know we resolved this question). Otherwise I'd have to answer the question myself, but it's better to give credit where credit is due ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a response to mark this question as answered. The user [Gorgious](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/86891/gorgious) linked a video which showed the solution: youtu.be/05HFa3jNBH0?t=24

The trick seems to be to switch to top-down, orthographic view, then project a UV map from view, shift the UV map over the desired part of the texture, then select 'individual origins' and scale the UV map projections of each object waaaaay down. Done =)

Thanks, Gorgious!